# extracting anchor values hidden in div tags

Tags: php, html

From a html page I need to extract the values of v from all anchor links…each anchor link is hidden in some 5 div tags

```
<a href="/watch?v=value to be retrived&amp;list=blabla&amp;feature=plpp_play_all">
```

Each v value has 11 characters, for this as of now am trying to read it by character by character like

```
<?php
$file=fopen("xx.html","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$d='v';
$dd='=';
$vd=array();
while (!feof($file))
  {
  $f=fgetc($file); 
  if($f==$d)
  {
  $ff=fgetc($file);
  if ($ff==$dd)
  { 
  $idea='';
  for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
  {      
$sData = fgetc($file);
$id=$id.$sData;
  }      
  array_push($vd, $id);
```

That is am getting each character of v and storing it in sData variable and pushing it into id so as to get those 11 characters as a string(id)…
the problem is…searching for the ‘v=’  through the entire html file and if found reading the 11characters and pushing it into a sData array is sucking, it is taking considerable amount of time…so pls help me to sophisticate the things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function substring(&$string,$start,$end)
{
    $pos = strpos(">".$string,$start);
    if(! $pos) return "";
    $pos--;
    $string = substr($string,$pos+strlen($start));
    $posend = strpos($string,$end);
    $toret = substr($string,0,$posend);
    $string = substr($string,$posend);
    return $toret;
}
$contents = @file_get_contents("xx.html");

$old="";
$videosArray=array();
while ($old <> $contents)
{
$old = $contents;
$v = substring($contents,"?v=","&");
if($v) $videosArray[] = $v;
}

//$videosArray is array of v's
?>
```

Comment: when i'm trying to load the contents dynamically from an url, it is taking more than triple the time, throwing an error :Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: This depends on the page (xx.html) size , if it's huge , you can add 

set_time_limit(0) at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

I would better parse HTML with SimpleXML and XPath:

```
// Get your page HTML string
$html = file_get_contents('xx.html');

// As per comment by Gordon to suppress invalid markup warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Create SimpleXML object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

// Find a nodes
$anchors = $xml->xpath('//a[contains(@href, "v=")]');

foreach ($anchors as $a)
{
    $href = (string)$a['href'];
    $url = parse_url($href);
    parse_str($url['query'], $params);

    // $params['v'] contains what we need
    $vd[] = $params['v']; // push into array
}

// Clear invalid markup error buffer
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Comment: it is throwing an error :  Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 1 in C:\wamp\www\php trails\php-html-gen.php on line 59..whr line 59 is $doc->loadHTML($html);

Comment: Suppress these warnings with `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`. It happens because some characters are not HTML valid entities, e.g `v=123&a=test` should be `v=123&amp;a=test`. Most of HTML markup is not valid so such warnings are almost always thrown although DOM would still load.

Comment: you should never suppress any errors with @ at all. Use `libxml_use_internal_errors` to collect parsing errors in memory instead of outputting them.