# Get tag value from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, youtube

My XML file looks like

```
<entry>
    some tags 
    <title type='text'> content to be extracted </title>
    <content type='text'> content to be extracted </content>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=content to be extracted &amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
</entry>
```

to achieve this if I use the following ...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadXML("kFeed.xml");
$entryTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("entry")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$title = $dom->$entryTag->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$descr = $dom->$entryTag->getElementsByTagName("content")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

It is throwing the following error like `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` for 4th line  and `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property` for 5th line.

Can someone please suggest me how to crack this and how to extract the 'v' value from the href of link (I have 4 links and I want that value which has rel='alternate').

And finally when I directly give an URL (instead kFeed.xml) to load XML it is not functioning, no error.

Comment: You have asked this already and even accepted the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968223/extracting-anchor-values-hidden-in-div-tags

Comment: @dfsq I'm unable to access the xml node values. for extracting the v value yes i've asked there bt this is entirely different situation where i want v value based on rel value of the link...each rel has different v values

Comment: My answer in that thread is full complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8968413/949476. Just change `a[contains(@href, "v=")` to `link[contains(@href, "v=")`

Comment: thanks, but can u help me in extracting the title and content description

Answer (score 4):

This will work for you

```
$str    =   "<entry>
some tags 
<title type='text'> content to be extracted </title>
<content type='text'> content to be extracted </content>
<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=content to be extracted &amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
</entry>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

echo $xml->title;    //Will print title

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml->link->attributes());   //Will print attributes also
```

Comment: i want it to be loaded from an url, which i'm nt able to

Comment: it is throwing the same error(stated in question) even if implement your suggestion

Comment: @pbvamsi Then you must use  **simplexml_load_file**    instead of **simplexml_load_string**

Comment: thanks but it is still throwing the same error as stated in the question

Comment: @pbvamsi I think your xml file may not contain any data . I have run the above string successfully in my machine ,as I am using php 5 . Check your php version

Answer (score 1):

`loadxml($xml)` expects $xml to be the xml data itself, not a pointer to a (file) source.
Use [DOMDocument::load($filename)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) instead.

And `$dom->$entryTag->...` won't work either. You might be interested in [DOMXPath](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) or [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Should you actually be accessing the item as an array rather than as an object?

```
$descr = $dom->$entryTag->getElementsByTagName("content")->item[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I wanna get those title and descr values, in the later stage i'll push them into an item array in the xml which i generate. In a word yes item is an array (where i put this title and description as child nodes)

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xx.xml');

$title = (string)$xml->title;
$content = (string)$xml->content;
$linkHref = (string)$xml->link['href'];

$url = parse_url($linkHref);
parse_str($url['query'], $params);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($params['v']); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: *this is useful* bt not able to pullout the content and it `Notice: Undefined index: v`